# Test arrays with same value in same position

Tags: c++

I have the following problem:

here it is...output summary is below.

Output Summary: Test two arrays to determine if they contain the same value in the same position. Write a main program that tests function isEqual. Using prototype: bool isEqual(int A[ ], int B[ ] )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


#define FLUSH  cin.clear(); while(cin.get()!='\n');

bool isEqual (int A[], int B[]);

int main()
{
    int index;
    bool matches[10] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int A[10] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 15, 7, 3, 1};
    int B[10] = {1, 3, 7, 2, 3, 11, 8, 9, 10, 0};

    for (index = 0; index <= 9; index++)
    {
        matches[index] = isEqual (A[index], B[index]);
    }
    if (matches[index] == 1)
    {
        cout << 1 << endl;
    }
}

bool isEqual (int A[], int B[])
{
     return (A == B);
}
```

I have to use the isEqual() prototype shown, but not sure how to get the correct values in the matches array.

Comment: What you are trying to do is fundamentally wrong, I'd suggest you revise what your professor has been teaching you up to now.

Comment: What is `isEqual` trying to do?  If you could comment your code saying exactly how you're approaching the problem it'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay

When you use the [] "operator", it checks the *value* of the array at that position

so lets say for array A, `A[1] == 3`, right? Same goes for B, `B[2] == 7`
Remember that arrays are 0 based, meaning that element 0 is in fact, the first element in the array (`B[0] == 1`).

so when you're calling "`isEqual(A[index], B[index])`", what actually happens is

(suppose that index == 0)

```
isEqual(2, 1);
```

You need to realise that you are in fact, passing two numbers AND NOT ARRAYS.

I don't like doing homeworks for you since you won't learn anything. But just to keep you on the right track, I'm pretty sure that the question can be rephrased as follow

Write a function "isEqual", that takes two arrays of `int`.
Inside that function, compare each numbers at the same index position for both arrays   inside a loop
`if (A[index] == B[index])...`

if all of those comparisons are true, then both arrays are equal.

I suggest that you also declare a global constant for your arrays size (10). Usually, the prototype of IsEqual would be `IsEqual(int A[], int B[], int ARRAY_SIZE)`, but your prototype isn't like that so you have to know how big your arrays are

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In its current form, `isEqual()` is not only incorrect (it just compares two pointers for equality), it is also impossible to implement correctly, since there is no way to tell the size of the input arrays. Assuming your professor isn't an idiot, I can only guess that you are expected to find that it fails your test.

As for getting "the correct values in the matches arrays", I don't think you are supposed call `isEqual()` for each element. Call it once over the entire pair of arrays.

Comment: You can tell the size of the input arrays with `sizeof(A) / sizeof(int)`.

Comment: sizeof is a little odd with arrays. IIRC, once the array's been passed into a function, sizeof returns the size of the pointer to the first element, rather than the size of the array.

Comment: @Maxim: as @Slavik81 suggests, that doesn't work. It returns `sizeof((int*)A) / sizeof(int)` which equals 1 or 2 on most hardware, regardless of the size of the arrays.

Comment: In order to find the size of an array parameter, it has to be passed by reference (and then the size is generally a template parameter, you still wouldn't use `sizeof`).